# Android Studio NDK error, couldn't find GLES3/gl3.h although it exist

Tags: opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm trying to make an app on Android Studio that use the NDK and OpenGL ES 3.0.When I #include < GLES3/gl3.h >, the IDE has auto completion as I typing, I think it's a sign meaning that the IDE can find it 
However, I got the error : **"Error:(22, 10) fatal error: 'GLES3/gl3.h' file not found"** when I build the project. I check the NDK path in Project Structure, which is :

```
sdk\ndk-bundle\platforms\android-21\arch-arm64\usr\include\GLES3
```

it's correct and the GLES3/gl3.h does exist there.

I have declared my CMakeList with GLESv3 already:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# now build app's shared lib
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -Wall")

add_library(gl3jni SHARED
            gl_code.cpp
            stb_image.cpp
            )

# add lib dependencies
target_link_libraries(gl3jni
                      android
                      log 
                      EGL
                      GLESv3)
```

I also declare the OpenGL ES version in the Manifest.xml with:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00030000" android:required="true"/>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you building for android-21?

Comment: How to check which version of android that I am building for? Sorry for a dumb question, but I'm new to Android Studio.

Comment: Search your project for "targetSdkVersion".

Comment: I found it. My project min sdk version is 18 and Target SDK Version is API 23. Do i have to set it back to API 21?

Comment: No, it doesn't need to be exact, just greater than or equal. I think when it comes to native code it's actually `compileSdkVersion` that gets used, but I'm not familiar with gradle tbh.

Answer (score 2):

Android ndk-bundle has openglES3 since api 18, but in arm platform.

I mean, if you are going to compile your project in armV8_64, you must set your min sdk to 21. But if you are going to use armeabi or armeabiV7 the minimum api will be 18.

So change your minSDK dependig on your preferences in the *app/build.gradle* file.

I suggest you to define the API 21 and define your product flavours to support for all architectures, besides you can make other 3rdparty library linkings, the code should be something like this:

```
android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
            ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file(''your_libraries_path'')}".toString())
            ndk.ldLibs.addAll(["your_armeabi_library"])
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
            ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file('your_libraries_path')}".toString())
            ndk.ldLibs.addAll(["your_armv7_library"])
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
            ndk.ldFlags.add("-L${file(''your_libraries_path')}".toString())
            ndk.ldLibs.addAll(["your_armv8_library"])
        }
}
```

This gradle code is from the gradle 0.8.3 experimental plugin, so if you have not this version, you need to make some changes to fit into your gradle version.

Answer (score 0):

For me I only have to change the minSdkVersion in build.gradle to 19.

Comment: Please See this first before answering.  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

do not forget to set

APP_PLATFORM := android-23 (or other depending on uelordi answer)

to application.mk